# Usage of anneal

Tags: usage

Definition of [anneal](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/anneal):

> When you anneal metal or glass, you heat it and then cool it in order
>   to make it less brittle and more malleable.

Is it explicitly used for metals and glass? Can I use to describe intensity of training such as

> Chinese coaches annealed children for Olympics

By saying this I want to emphasise on rigours training they gave to the children. Is this proper?

Comment: It would be understood as a (somewhat unusual) metaphorical use of the word **anneal**.  `Training : Children :: Annealing : Metal`.

Comment: The more common metaphors for "toughened by undergoing a difficult process" would be 'tempered' or 'forged'.

Comment: anneal is only a technical term.

Comment: Unless the coaches literally heated and cooled the children, I would not use it. @John has given you some better alternatives.

Comment: What you wrote is a usage example, not a definition. The definition I checked, [*anneal*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/anneal), does not mention specific materials, and "3. *(transitive)* to toughen or strengthen (the will, determination, etc)" could apply to your example.

Comment: [**Simulated annealing**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) is a well-known *probabilistic technique for approximating the global optimum of a given function.* But OP's example strikes me as a metaphoric stretch too far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

English is a language that loves metaphor, so you definitely have the right idea.  There is nothing wrong with using a phrase meant to apply to physical materials as a metaphor for some *human* process, and of course writing style is very much a matter of personal choice. *However*, as with any language, not every word is appropriate for every context.

The problem I see with "anneal" is that it's not often used, and so the meaning might not be clear to your audience.  As I said, there's nothing wrong with it, but you might consider that there are already common expressions to describe what you want to say:

> He was *forged* by merciless training and strict discipline.
>
> Her will became *hardened like diamond* from the continual stress of the internship program.
>
> A few months in the military *hammered* his body into solid steel.

As well as many others.  This is the ongoing challenge for any writer -- to pick *exactly* the right word to accurately convey what you want to express.